Can't install Freecad from PPA in Noble
Has Freecad been dropped from Noble?
apt install freecad

results in Package 'freecad' has no installation candidate
even when I add the PPA as described on the Freecad website...

freecad open source parametric 3D CAD modeler has been dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 24.04. You get an officially supported alternative to the PPA version of FreeCAD by installing the freecad snap package.
To install the freecad snap package in Ubuntu 24.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo snap install freecad

There are multiple apps/commands included in the snap:

freecad:               Run FreeCAD
freecad.cmd:      Run FreeCAD command line interface
freecad.pip:        Install python packages for user (not system-wide).

Side note: There is a FreeCAD experimental branch called 'Link branch'
created by a user named 'realthunder' that has become popular. It is
available as a snap package named freecad-realthunder. To list all freecad snap packages run snap find freecad .
